# Verilog counter does not work

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, counter, testbench

I've written this code for a counter, but I don't know why it doesn't work.  The output remains at zero, and when I change load to 0, output changes to unknown.

Would you please help me to find the error?

```
module behav_counter( d, clk, clear, load, up_down, qd);

 input   [7:0] d;
 input   clk;
 input   clear;
 input   load;
 input   up_down;
 output  [7:0] qd;

 reg     [7:0] cnt;

always @ (posedge clk or negedge clear)
if (!clear)
    cnt = 8'h00;
else if (load)
    cnt = d;
else if (up_down)
    cnt = cnt + 1;
else
    cnt = cnt - 1;

assign qd = cnt;

endmodule

module test_b;

  reg d,clk,clear,load,up_down;
  wire qd;

  behav_counter bc( d, clk, clear, load, up_down, qd);

  initial
  begin
       clear = 0;
       clk = 0;
       #15 clear = 1; 
       repeat (400)
         #5 clk = ~clk;
  end

  initial 
  begin
     up_down=1;
     load=1;
     d=8'h00;
     #23
     load=0;
     #100
     load=1;
   end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

When I run your code on 2 different simulators, I get compile warnings about port size differences for `d` and `qd`.  Your counter declares them as 8-bit wide, but you connect 1-bit signals to them.  If you don't get warnings, try it on edaplayground.

In `test_b`, declare them as 8-bit:

```
module test_b;
 reg clk,clear,load,up_down;
 reg  [7:0] d;
 wire [7:0] qd;
```

Now I see `qd[7:0]` count up from 0 to 0xa when `load`=0.